# Redis write to log and view log

Tags: redis

When executing an eval script from a remote location.

How can we log so we can evaluate what is happening?

```
        local name = KEYS[1]
        local key  = KEYS[2]
        
        local desired   = ARGV[1]
        local expecting = ARGV[2]
        local expires   = ARGV[3]
        local channel   = ARGV[4]  
        local message   = ARGV[5]

        redis.log(...) ?
```

And where does such logs go? How can they be viewed?

Comment: To write to the log you can use something like `redis.log(redis.LOG_WARNING, "foo bar")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configured `logfile` in redis.conf, the logs will go to that file. If  `logfile` is empty string, i.e. the default value, and redis-server is not daemonized, the logs will be printed to standard output. If it's empty, and redis-server is daemonized, logs go to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Did you read my question? I would like to send something to the log from my lua script. what is the command? redis.log( ...  ) ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `redis.log` to do log in script, and the log goes to where I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: hehe  i was just guessing with my pseudo code ;)